# Replace all Numeric Values with Single Character

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, replace

I have a value in a SQL table like the below:

***80400365_SwapOpenTrd_20180831.csv***

I want to replace the numeric values so it is returned as this:

***%_SwapOpenTrd_%.csv***

I tried the below code but there are groups of % characters returned...

***%%%%%%%%_SwapOpenTrd_%%%%%%%%%csv***

What do I need to change here to get desired result?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/33261

```
DECLARE @Temp nvarchar(150) = '80400365_SwapOpenTrd_20180831.csv'

Declare @KeepValues as varchar(50)
Set @KeepValues = '%[^a-z_% ]%' -- keep underscore and space
While PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp) > 0
    Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp), 1, '%')

select @Temp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your latest comment, I made few changes to your original example.  The following logic prevents repetitive `%` from being stuffed.

See if this works for you.

```
DECLARE @Temp NVARCHAR(150) = 'Numara_03_09_2018_07_41_04_OP_NIP_CSA_5739038.XLS'
DECLARE @KeepValues AS VARCHAR(50)

SET @KeepValues = '%[^a-z_%. ]%' -- keep underscore and space

WHILE PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @Temp = CASE 
            WHEN substring(@temp, PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp) - 1, 1) = '%'
                THEN Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp), 1, '')
            ELSE Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp), 1, '%')
            END
END

SELECT @Temp
```

---

Result

```
Numara_%_%_%_%_%_%_OP_NIP_CSA_%.XLS
```

Comment: If the filename is like this then it won't work... Numara_03_09_2018_07_41_04_OP_NIP_CSA_5739038.XLS

Comment: @Kevin - Using the example in your comment, what should the result be?

Comment: This...Numara_%_%_%_%_%_%_OP_NIP_CSA_%XLS  - where groups of numbers are replaced with single %